# .htaccess redirect old URL to new URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this httpd-vhosts.conf in xampp

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName midolibarr.com
    Redirect / http://midolibarr.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName midolibarr.com
    DocumentRoot C:/xampp7/htdocs/
    ErrorLog C:/xampp7/apache/logs/error.log
    CustomLog C:/xampp7/apache/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I have these folders

- `C:\xampp7\htdocs\dolibarr` -> Contains Dolibarr installation with all it's files
- `C:\xampp7\htdocs\dolibarr-old-url` -> Contains a single `.htaccess` file
- `C:\xampp7\htdocs\dolibarr2` -> Contains Dolibarr installation with all it's files
- `C:\xampp7\htdocs\dolibar3` -> Contains Dolibarr installation with all it's files

The `.htaccess` file contains this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dolibarr-old-url/(.*)$ /dolibarr/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Why isn't the redirection working??

If I try anything `http://midolibarr.com/dolibarr-old-url/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` I get a 404 error.

I can't think of any reason for it not working, URL seem correct no typos.
I've tried restarting apache, incognito, different browsers.

Comment: The path RewriteRule matches against, it relative to the directory the .htaccess is in. So if you have it _in_ the folder C:\xampp7\htdocs\dolibarr-old-url\, then it will not start with `dolibarr-old-url/`.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dolibarr/$1 [R=301,NC,L]` worked, if you want to add an answer I'll accept it. @CBroe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> RewriteRule ^dolibarr-old-url/(.*)$ /dolibarr/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

The path RewriteRule matches against, it relative to the directory the .htaccess is in.

So if you have it in the folder `C:\xampp7\htdocs\dolibarr-old-url\`, then it will not start with `dolibarr-old-url/`

You need to match just `^(.*)$`, to match and capture the part that comes after the folder name in your URL.